# Checking if two GeoJSONs overlap

Tags: javascript, geojson, turfjs

I've got two valid GeoJSONs. I'm trying to understand whether they overlap. I've been trying to use line-intersect from Turf.js, like this:

```
import { lineIntersect } from '@turf/turf';
if (lineIntersect(e.layer.toGeoJSON(), realGeoJSON)) 
    {
         console.log (lineIntersect(e.layer.toGeoJSON(), realGeoJSON));
    }
```

Unfortunately, this just brings back an empty feature collection.

For instance, here are two features which overlap (one contains the other,) yet when I run lineIntersect on them, I get an empty result:

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[34.38151665119666,31.47890462548891,0],[34.24131053682105,31.39519970105964,0],[34.20391229566884,31.31046528984165,0],[34.31023972371427,31.12192885120737,0],[34.32238143660881,31.09608541854309,0],[34.32845010662197,31.08316227875504,0],[34.3399878573332,31.05111274029189,0],[34.3819736618827,30.87941536483305,0],[34.4625794738603,30.65469000345236,0],[34.46079897849552,30.63605651330755,0],[34.48093837332151,30.54064393834374,0],[34.48701144862344,30.52765539371588,0],[34.55491673915576,30.3971320487581,0],[34.57859864255086,30.33884544466566,0],[34.5841010709255,30.3195774836368,0],[34.59568048671346,30.28726986771069,0],[34.59452479274348,30.27479275329208,0],[34.62488304800757,30.20958854031441,0],[34.6387603290821,30.20222082678984,0],[34.71436347629015,30.07682031495306,0],[34.71259779426985,30.05809037881291,0],[34.71628915470217,30.02005342200006,0],[34.75076906620446,29.92290870131085,0],[34.75680680602306,29.90983473619655,0],[34.86200494951397,29.78080306661147,0],[34.86038824538134,29.76186588722682,0],[34.85985465965802,29.75554744508348,0],[34.87458404107667,29.67157102811895,0],[34.87967097237944,29.64566203932595,0],[34.88079268646108,29.57563973494665,0],[34.90538890070649,29.52945734421175,0],[34.98109436237601,29.5542870425272,0],[35.03949367509274,29.63847028614006,0],[35.09890268380539,29.73532624342861,0],[35.10662487673798,29.74108861079644,0],[35.15838643590403,29.83204001172806,0],[35.17581417200116,29.86220648447516,0],[35.17642201553415,29.86846832766622,0],[35.22752559603887,29.94641218538877,0],[35.23716690705381,29.97087168207232,0],[35.26672235396222,30.05048288346658,0],[35.27039417463298,30.08801137042606,0],[35.28897082403768,30.13071126439134,0],[35.18979861092051,30.25551467908188,0],[35.38491270168139,30.93027973988132,0],[35.45082126925127,31.06594264974105,0],[35.44722368690986,31.24990699939903,0],[35.39159459673273,31.49811901942546,0],[35.30663360486346,31.50514564876487,0],[35.22682220736229,31.51219288891959,0],[35.20182280376471,31.50399372918324,0],[35.20257232954722,31.51072084692123,0],[35.17845425556429,31.50456774949482,0],[35.17715019191054,31.5080912969423,0],[35.17584130839815,31.51161346815049,0],[35.17615545360398,31.51499006142148,0],[35.17634008732453,31.51701656989114,0],[35.19462720371881,31.51275211889307,0],[35.17373380395745,31.50634219008566,0],[35.17211642460078,31.50648424243521,0],[35.13663682917868,31.50923658211334,0],[35.10997231069795,31.50448491651967,0],[35.11045603614101,31.50175523199227,0],[35.10608104898849,31.49803734440621,0],[35.09319760456682,31.49631331040035,0],[35.0640867946593,31.4910299229135,0],[35.04236314932221,31.49608863302037,0],[35.02071025749389,31.50178829489378,0],[34.99360687527013,31.50914407573474,0],[34.98304638712193,31.51529139391714,0],[34.9607716570927,31.50874723841895,0],[34.96284549594341,31.51335157521662,0],[34.96554955203035,31.51652570530491,0],[34.96821565782273,31.51905477026719,0],[34.96915140126914,31.5203480011361,0],[34.95586297893289,31.50774103465133,0],[34.96594857172293,31.52806484995884,0],[34.96852953236886,31.53740852679276,0],[34.96525541695491,31.54445456073684,0],[34.96827302996868,31.55035702098375,0],[34.97157587431909,31.55896103778682,0],[34.97479844343971,31.56688530825338,0],[34.97513871614513,31.57026095463069,0],[34.97520672211002,31.57093623752663,0],[34.96206021732661,31.5910034931354,0],[34.96133836855449,31.591739276496,0],[34.94070502436983,31.60148403071715,0],[34.92241820431752,31.61106005296995,0],[34.89434374334633,31.60392503100067,0],[34.80687543628677,31.61045864537442,0],[34.79957082732486,31.61099992786523,0],[34.73003921185517,31.64144693398919,0],[34.63718286917748,31.65305512858577,0],[34.54700252433163,31.66989760698388,0],[34.52042121323742,31.61883522021243,0],[34.38151665119666,31.47890462548891,0]]]}}
,{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[34.928146,30.991737],[35.103928,30.982319],[35.005051,30.897511],[34.928146,30.991737]]]}}  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that using Turf's booleanWithin function works. I'm also using booleanOverlaps for those edge cases. Like this:

```
if (
    booleanWithin(e.layer.toGeoJSON(), realGeoJSON) || booleanOverlaps(e.layer.toGeoJSON(), realGeoJSON)) 
      {this.props.setNewPlotRegion(a.RegionName);}
```

Comment: I just glanced at the `booleanOverlap()` code. I believe it may not cover the case where one GeoJSON lies entirely inside of another with no intersecting lines. I will say that I expect `booleanOverlap()` to be more reliable than `intersect()` other than this edge case. So if you don't need to cover that case, then probably it is a better choice than my answer above.

Comment: @ErikHermansen that's exactly why he uses booleanWithin as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use `intersect()` (@turf/intersect) which returns a Feature representing all the shapes covering the intersection of your two GeoJSONs.

If you want to just know, true or false, if anything intersects between the two, any non-null response from the API will indicate intersection.

On the other hand, if you want to check for a case of overlapping instead of just intersection (the intersected shapes have area and are not just shared edges or points), the response needs to be parsed with an algorithm like this:

`* If feature.geometry.type is "Polygon" or "MultiPolygon" then return true (it overlaps)
* If feature.geometry.type is "GeometryCollection" then iterate through all members in the collection and return true if a "Polygon" or "MultiPolygon" is found.
* Otherwise, return false. (no overlap)`